# How to create a local postgresql database on user pc

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

I have some (amateur) experience developing simple softwares in my company to help in our engineering calculation routines. For that, I got access to the company postgres server, created a database and have been using it in my software. When I distributed it to my coworkers I had no problems because we are all in the same network.

Now I'm willing to start a personal project at home to help a friend who is starting a small business. Since I have some knowledge of postgresql, I intend to use it as a database for customers, suppliers, goods, etc. But to do so I'll have to install Postgress on my PC. I'll write my application, test it and everything will go fine. But then, when I install my software in my friends computer, it will not have the postgres database I created in my PC at home.

Can you guys help me with the best way to create a software that uses postgres and distribute it to the final user who is not sharing a network with me?

Or maybe, since I'm not a professional, there is a much better solution that I don't know of and you can show me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PostgreSQL is not a good choice for that. You need an *embedded database*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want that your friend uses that postgres database you have 2 options:

- Install postgres on your friend's machine and then you make a backup of your database and import them on his pc and thus he would access locally from his computer with `localhost` or from his local network with any pc (in this case his pc should have static IP).
- The second option would be to mount the database on a web hosting that allows postgresql and so your friend with internet could access the database from anywhere.

A better opcion should be using an embedded on the software like SQLite

Comment: Looks like SQLite is the way to go. I'll just wait a little bit to accept this answer as a good practice in stackoverflow. Many thanks

Comment: Glad to help you!